# Wordpress query_posts avoid content

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a wordpress page to display the list of posts of a specific category.
I use the function `query_posts` in the following way:

```
$posts =  query_posts(array('category_name'=>'formazione'));
```

My problem is that the function shows the post content even without the loop and redirect the output to the `$posts` variable.

How can I avoid displaying the post content?

Comment: Do **not** use `query_posts`, **ever**. It breaks the main query which you should avoid doing at all costs. Also, do not use `$posts` as a custom variable, you are breaking the `$posts` global. Rather use `$posts_array` instead

Comment: you are right but I am inside of a stand alone page. Therefore, no other query should be necessary. I wish I could avoid it but since I have to show some posts inside of this page I have no choice

Comment: Stand alone page, like you are creating in back end?. If so, use `WP_Query`. If not, use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the variable $posts to start with, as said in the comments to your question.

Ideally look at using get_posts() https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts instead to get your posts. There are examples at the bottom of that page on how to use it.

```
$args = array( 'category_name' => 'formazione' );
$myposts = get_posts($args);
```

Etc... look at the page for how to handle $myposts data that comes back.